# Retrieve an HTMLelement structure as an array of objects treestructure

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0jrtwoe/14/)

#### my el:

```
<div id="parent1">

  <div id="child1">
  </div>

  <div id="child2">
  </div>

  <div id="child3">
  </div>

  <p id="hehe_ignore"> completely ignore </p>

  <div id="parent2">

      <p> completely ignore </p>

      <div id="child4">

         <p id="hehe_ignore2"> completely ignore </p>

      </div>

      <div id="child5">
      </div>

      <div id="child6">
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

#### my desired js obj:

```
[
  {parent1: [
      {child1: []},
      {child2: []},
      {child3: []},
      {parent2: [
          {child4: []},
          {child5: []},
          {child6: []},
      ]}
  ]}
];
```

What is the fastest and best way to to this in vanilla js?

- NO jquery
- NO thirdparty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based off the HTML markup in [your **fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d0jrtwoe/14/) (which differs from the HTML markup currently seen in your question, but the solution here should work on your question's HTML, too):

[JSFiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/6Ltqsyh3/1/)

```js
const buildTree = node => {
  if (!node.childNodes) {
    return [];
  }

  const childrenWithIDs = [];

  [...node.childNodes].forEach(childNode => {
    if (childNode.nodeName === "DIV" && childNode.id) {
      childrenWithIDs.push({
        [childNode.id]: buildTree(childNode)
      })
    }
  });

  return childrenWithIDs;
}

const rootEl = document.getElementById("parent1").parentNode;
const result = buildTree(rootEl);
console.log(result);
```

It wasn't clear what you specifically wanted to ignore, so I tracked nodes that were `div` elements with an `id` (but you could just modify the conditional to check for whatever you want).

The only change I made to the code in your fiddle was to start the process with the parent node of `#parent1`. It would presumably be possible to achieve the same result while starting the process directly with `#parent1`, but it seemed simpler to start from the node's parent.

I assume that should be fine, as there would always be a parent node for every node, even the `<html>` tag (as long as you target the `parentNode`, not the `parentElement`, as the latter would return `null` for the `<html>` tag).

Comment: thank you, somehow it did not update my fiddle, but I can tweek your solution.